# Exception when attempting to link an object to the currently authenticated user

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I currently have an ASP.NET Web Api 2 application which, for the purposes of this question, manages 'Items'. ASP.NET Identity 2 is used to provide authentication for requests, and the data is handed by Entity Framework 6.

My aim is for the item's Owner property to be set automatically to the user who authenticated the POST request. Below is the code so far:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostItem(Item item)
{           
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

    // Set the Owner to the currently authenticated user
    item.Owner = user;

    db.Items.Add(item); // Exception Thrown Here

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    ...
}
```

However, when the method is called, the following exception occurs. The current userId and user are being found correctly, yet there is still an issue adding the Item once its Owner property has been set.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by
>   multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Comment: are you using code first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to track the same entity using two different contexts and that doesn't work. maybe you should look in your code and see which of your entities is being tracked by two context, It is possible since you are using a global variable (`db`) as a reference to your context.

Comment: It turns out that my UserManager was being created using a different instance of the DbContext. Changing the initialisation to use the same DbContext resolved the issue. Thanks @dotctor for pointing me in the right direction!